# How to get list of all queries in Access database using ODBC connection

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

I am able to get list of all tables using

ODBCConnection.GetSchema("tables", null)

How to get list of all queries present in the database?

Comment: Have you tried `GetSchema("Views")`?

Comment: @GordThompson I seem to recall that views in ado only returns select queries, not action queries. I have no idea what happens in c#

Comment: Eventually I came across this OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames and figured there is Views in the list(until then I was trying with Queries) but this lists only select queries and update, delete etc are not listed.

Comment: Try procedures for action queries.

Comment: Procedures throw exception.

Comment: Are you saying that you are connecting to an Access database via ODBC from something other than Access? The following query should return all queries. SELECT MSysObjects.Name, MSysObjects.Type
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "~*") AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=5))
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;